# How to obtain the results of a Tukey HSD post-hoc test in a table showing grouped pairs?

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I would love to perform a TukeyHSD post-hoc test after my two-way Anova with R, obtaining a table containing the sorted pairs grouped by significant difference. (Sorry about the wording, I'm still new with statistics.)

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

So, grouped with stars or letters.

Any idea? I tested the function `HSD.test()` from the `agricolae` package, but it seems it doesn't handle two-way tables.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `agricolae::HSD.test` function does exactly that, but you will need to let it know that *you are interested in an interaction term*. Here is an example with a Stata dataset:

```
library(foreign)
yield <- read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/yield.dta")
tx <- with(yield, interaction(fertilizer, irrigation))
amod <- aov(yield ~ tx, data=yield)
library(agricolae)
HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)
```

This gives the results shown below:

```
Groups, Treatments and means
a        2.1     51.17547 
ab       4.1     50.7529 
abc      3.1     47.36229 
 bcd     1.1     45.81229 
  cd     5.1     44.55313 
   de    4.0     41.81757 
    ef   2.0     38.79482 
    ef   1.0     36.91257 
     f   3.0     36.34383 
     f   5.0     35.69507
```

They match what we would obtain with the following commands:

```
. webuse yield
. regress yield fertilizer##irrigation
. pwcompare fertilizer#irrigation, group mcompare(tukey)

-------------------------------------------------------
                      |                           Tukey
                      |     Margin   Std. Err.   Groups
----------------------+--------------------------------
fertilizer#irrigation |
                 1 0  |   36.91257   1.116571    AB    
                 1 1  |   45.81229   1.116571      CDE 
                 2 0  |   38.79482   1.116571    AB    
                 2 1  |   51.17547   1.116571         F
                 3 0  |   36.34383   1.116571    A     
                 3 1  |   47.36229   1.116571       DEF
                 4 0  |   41.81757   1.116571     BC   
                 4 1  |    50.7529   1.116571        EF
                 5 0  |   35.69507   1.116571    A     
                 5 1  |   44.55313   1.116571      CD  
-------------------------------------------------------
Note: Margins sharing a letter in the group label are
      not significantly different at the 5% level.
```

The [multcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html) package also offers symbolic visualization ('compact letter displays', see [Algorithms for Compact Letter Displays: Comparison and Evaluation](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hueffner/letter-displays-csda06.pdf) for more details) of significant pairwise comparisons, although it does not present them in a tabular format. However, it has a plotting method which allows to conveniently display results using boxplots. Presentation order can be altered as well (option `decreasing=`), and it has lot more options for multiple comparisons. There is also the [multcompView](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcompView/index.html) package which extends those functionalities.

Here is the same example analyzed with `glht`:

```
library(multcomp)
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tx = "Tukey"))
summary(tuk)          # standard display
tuk.cld <- cld(tuk)   # letter-based display
opar <- par(mai=c(1,1,1.5,1))
plot(tuk.cld)
par(opar)
```

Treatment sharing the same letter are not significantly different, at the chosen level (default, 5%).

[image]

Incidentally, there is a new project, currently hosted on R-Forge, which looks promising: [factorplot](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1111). It includes line and letter-based displays, as well as a matrix overview (via a level plot) of all pairwise comparisons. A working paper can be found here: [factorplot: Improving Presentation of Simple Contrasts in GLMs](http://www.quantoid.net/factorplot_armstrong.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much for this exhaustive answer! I will be trying those different methods as soon as I get a few minutes.
Cheers!

Comment: I tried the multcomp package function, put when I use the 'cld()' function I get the error 'Error: sapply(split_names, length) == 2 is not all TRUE'
Any idea why?

Comment: @chtfn There seems to be a problem with variable labels. A quick look at the source code indicates that this error message comes from `insert_absorb()` which tries to extract pair of treatments. You can perhaps try to change the separator you used for coding levels of your interaction term? Without a working example, it's hard to tell what happened.

Comment: I figured it out: I had points in my genotypes and treatments' names, and as qlht() uses a point to divide the pair names, it freaked out.
Thank you so much for all your help, chl! :)

Comment: I noticed today that I now have to add `console=TRUE` in `HSD.test()` in order to get the tables, in case someone tries this and sees no result.
Probably an update of `agricolae`.

Comment: Does anyone know why `agricolae::HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)$groups` and `cld(glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tx = "Tukey")), decreasing=TRUE)` produce slightly different results? The group '3.1' is 'abc' according to agricolae::HSD.test but 'ac' according to multcomp::glht.

Comment: @jordi Both results agree (see `print(HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)$groups)`); the problem comes from the graphical display delivered by the `cld()` function. I haven't investigate much into its code, though.

Answer (score 3):

There's a function called `TukeyHSD` that, according to the help file, calculates a set of confidence intervals on the differences between the means of the levels of a factor with the specified family-wise probability of coverage. The intervals are based on the Studentized range statistic, Tukey's "Honest Significant Difference" method. Does this do what you want?

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/TukeyHSD.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I tried this function, but it gives me raw lists of comparisons. What I would like is to see them grouped like in the image in my question, to have a clear view of which group differs to which group, and eventually add the group names on my graphs (for example: a, ab, abc, bc, c)