# How to obtain the results of the Nemenyi post-hoc test in a table showing grouped pairs?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, friedman-test

I performed a Friedman's test, which showed that there are differences among my treatments. Thus, I choose to perform the Nemenyi's post-hoc test in order to infer which treatments statistically differ among them. Thus, I used the `posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test` from the `PMCMR` package to perform pairwise comparisons between treatments.

Now, I want to divide my treatments into groups, like the example below.

```
Treatment 1    a
Treatment 2    ab
Treatment 3     b
Treatment 4      c
```

**My question is**: Given the p-values of a multiple-comparison post-hoc test, how can I split my treatments into groups as the above example?

---

**Note**: This question is very similar to [How to obtain the results of a Tukey HSD post-hoc test in a table showing grouped pairs?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/how-to-obtain-the-results-of-a-tukey-hsd-post-hoc-test-in-a-table-showing-groupe). However, I want to get this information for the Nemenyi's test instead of the Tukey's test.

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I do that?"? Are you asking for code? (Note that questions that are only about how to use software are off topic here.)

Comment: This is virtually the same question as pointed in my reference (that was answered here in Cross Validated). I want an algorithm (or the idea of an algorithm) to perform such a task, not the code itself. I edited the question for a clearer objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more of research, I found a R code that solved this question. However, I still don't know how it works.

---

It is possible to use the `multcompLetters` function of the `multcompView` package along with the `fullPTable` function of the `rcompanion` package.

Thus, the following code outputs the grouped treatments:

```
if(!require(multcompView)){install.packages("multcompView")}
if(!require(PMCMR)){install.packages("PMCMR")}
if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion")}

library(PMCMR)
library(rcompanion)
library(multcompView)

pTable  = posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test(input)$p.value
pTableComplete = fullPTable(pTable)
multcompLetters(pTableComplete)
```